# Mkvmerge batch for change default audio

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I want to change the default audio of my files but there are too many.

How can I do it with cmd or bat file?

This is my code for one file:

```
"C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output ^"//vmware-host/Shared Folders/Desktop/New folder/C/Fairy Tail - 001.mkv^" --subtitle-tracks 4 --language 0:und --track-name 0:AVC-HD --default-track 0:yes --language 1:eng --track-name 1:AAC --language 2:jpn --track-name 2:Japanese --default-track 2:yes --language 4:eng --track-name 4:English --default-track 4:yes ^"^(^" ^"//vmware-host/Shared Folders/Desktop/New folder/A/Fairy Tail -001.mkv^" ^"^)^" --track-order 0:0,0:2,0:1,0:4
```

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hint: [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN ('dir /b *.MKV') DO "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "new_%%A" -a !3 --default-track 2:yes "%%A"

PAUSE
```